# What are Google font alternatives for Franklin Gothic

Tags: fonts, google, typekit

What are Google font alternatives for Franklin Gothic? I need an alternative to Franklin Gothic in Google Font Library.

Answer (score 3):

Google Font's version of it would be [Libre Franklin](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Franklin). There are some small differences but it's very close.